# Converting a non-decimal number to a decimal-based number

Tags: php

I have a number in php formatted as `5299`, and I'd like for it to be converted to a number that's decimal formatted as `52.99` to resemble money. I've messed around with php's `number_format()` but it doesn't seem like there is a way to add decimals for converting to cents. This number is dynamically calculated, so the `5299` might be `12122`, where `5299` would be `52.99` and `12122` would be converted to `121.22`.

Comment: What's the problem to divide the number by 100?

Comment: @user1597430, what do you mean by divide the number by 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple function like this.

```
<?php

$value = 50;

echo number_format(($value /100), 2, '.', ' ');

?>
```

Comment: Yeah I'm not the greatest at math, this fixed my problem. thanks